# How to send a message to a specific channel?

Tags: javascript, node.js, bots, discord, discord.js

I'm building a reminder bot for Discord.

The server owner or moderator should subscribe to the server via a message.
I'm having trouble finding the way to send the message to the specific server and channel.

Any idea if there is a way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have the channel ID all you need to do is find the channel and send a message to it:

```
let channel = client.channels.get('THECHANNELID');
if(channel) {
    channel.send("My Message");
}
```